# Найти самое большое слово в строке + сделать проверку

Tags: java

Всем привет! 
Надо найти самое большое слово в строке. + Сделать проверку чтобы в слове не было цифр или других знаков. Как это можно сделать не используя "regex"?
Мой г... код. Что я делаю не так?

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "444Everything you need to know about the Boeing";
        System.out.println(maxWord(test));
    }


    public static String maxWord(String input) {

        if (input == null)
            return null;

        String[] strings = input.split(" ");
        String maxWord = strings[0];

        for (String maxString : strings) {
            if (checkWords(maxString)) {
                if (maxString.length() > maxWord.length())
                    maxWord = maxString;
            }
        }
        return maxWord;
    }

    private static boolean checkWords(String input) {

        char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
        for (char letter : chars) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(letter)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return !input.isEmpty();
    }

    }
```

Comment: Самое простое - прогнать строку поэлементно str[i] , сравнивая каждый элемент на существование в алфавите, после этого , если элемент есть в алфавите - инкрементировать переменную sum++ , а если его там нет - записывать sum в результирующее значение res = sum; , полсе чего обнулять ее sum=0 .

Comment: Вам именно через regex надо?

Comment: Я хочу именно без regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что Вы без проверки установили первое слово как результат поиска

```
 String maxWord = strings[0];
```

а дальше все верно, но эта строка длиннее всех остальных

```
  if (maxString.length() > maxWord.length())
```

Можно инициализировать эту переменную пустой строкой, тогда все будет как Вы задумали:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "444Everything you need to know about the Boeing";
        System.out.println(maxWord(test));
    }
    public static String maxWord(String input) {
        if (input == null)
            return null;
        String[] strings = input.split(" ");
        String maxWord = "";
        for (String maxString : strings) {
            if (checkWords(maxString)) {
                if (maxString.length() > maxWord.length())
                    maxWord = maxString;
            }
        }
        return maxWord;
    }

    private static boolean checkWords(String input) {
        char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
        for (char letter : chars) {
            if (!Character.isLetter(letter)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return !input.isEmpty();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "444Everything you need to know about the Boeing";
    String[] words = test.split(" ");
    long maxLength = Arrays.stream(words)
      .map(CharSequence::chars)
      .filter(chars -> chars.allMatch(c -> (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')))
      .map(IntStream::count)
      .mapToLong(Long::longValue)
      .max()
      .orElse(0);
    System.out.println(maxLength);
  }
}
```